# Spring MVC project not displaying mysql data in view's table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I've set up a maven ,spring mvc webapp, crud project. When i Run my view page, my table doesn't show any of the data from the database.

My Controller

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.eoh.imp.service.AssetService;
import com.eoh.imp.model.Asset;

@Controller
public class AssetController {

@Autowired
private AssetService assetService;


@RequestMapping(value = "/ManageAssets", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView newAsset(ModelAndView model) {
    Asset asset = new Asset();
    List<Asset> listAsset = assetService.listAsset();
    model.addObject("asset", asset);
    model.addObject("listAssets",listAsset);
    model.setViewName("ManageInventory");
    return model;
}
```

My DAO

```
 import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
 import java.util.List;
 import org.hibernate.Criteria;
 import org.hibernate.Session;
 import com.eoh.imp.model.Asset;

@Repository
public class AssetDAOImpl implements AssetDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void addAsset(Asset a) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(a);
}

public Asset updateAsset(Asset a) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(a);
    return a;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Asset> listAsset() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Asset.class);
    return (List<Asset>)criteria.list();
}
```

View

```
<!-------------------------------------- ASSETS TABLE ---------------------------------------------->
<table class="table table-hover">

    <tr>
        <th>Asset Type</th>
        <th>Asset Make</th>
        <th>Asset Model</th>
        <th>Serial Number</th>
        <th>Date Of Purchase</th>
        <th>Supplier</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
        <th>Life Span</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>

    <c:forEach var="assets" items="${listAssets}">
        <tr>
            <td>${assets.getType()}</td>
            <td>${assets.getMake()}</td>
            <td>${assets.getModel()}</td>
            <td>${assets.getSerialNumber()}</td>
            <td>${assets.getDateOfPurchase()}</td>
            <td>${assets.getSupplier()}</td>
            <td>${assets.getComments()}</td>
            <td>${assets.getLifeSpan()}</td>
            <td><a href="editAsset?id=${assets.getId()}"
                class="btn btn-info col-lg-6"><span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a> <a
                href="deleteAsset?id=${assets.getId()}"
                class="btn btn-danger col-lg-6"><span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>

</table>
```

Output
[ManageAssets.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQnaD.png)

Database has 1 Asset

mysql> select * from Assets;

| id | type   | make   | model         | serialnumber | dateofpurchase | supplier | comments | lifespan |

|  1 | Laptop | Lenovo | ThinkPad W510 |              | NULL           |          |          | NULL     |

Comment: Have you tried to debug? Is the `listAsset` you store in the model empty or not?

Comment: The "listAsset" is not empty. but when i put a c tag <c:if test="${!empty listAssets}"> ,around <table>, to test if "listAssets" is empty, the table doesnt show.

Comment: Do you have data here `List<Asset> listAsset = assetService.listAsset();`

Comment: Yes. I do. added - System.out.println(listAsset.get(0)); - After that bit. Output : id=1, type=Laptop, make=Lenovo, model=ThinkPad W510, serialnumber=, dateofpurchase=null, supplier=, comments=, lifespan=null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed!!!!!
Problem was in my web.xml, was missing this bit:

```
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0"
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use c:out tag

```
<!-------------------------------------- ASSETS TABLE ---------------------------------------------->
<table class="table table-hover">

    <tr>
       <th>Asset Type</th>
        <th>Asset Make</th>
        <th>Asset Model</th>
        <th>Serial Number</th>
    <th>Date Of Purchase</th>
    <th>Supplier</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
    <th>Life Span</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
</tr>

<c:forEach var="assets" items="${listAssets}">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${assets.getType()}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${assets.getMake()}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${assets.getModel()}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${assets.getSerialNumber()}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${assets.getDateOfPurchase()}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${assets.getSupplier()}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${assets.getComments()}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${assets.getLifeSpan()}"/></td>
        <td><a href="editAsset?id=${assets.getId()}"
            class="btn btn-info col-lg-6"><span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a> <a
            href="deleteAsset?id=${assets.getId()}"
            class="btn btn-danger col-lg-6"><span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks...Tried it but same output.

Answer (score 0):

In JSP EL You don't call the method like that but you use the attribute name (or if it is a method with name like `getThing()`, you write `asset.thing)`:

`${assets.getType()}`  **wrong**

`${assets.type}`   **correct**

**EDIT:** Does this work? `<c:out value="${assets.type}"/>`

Comment: weird.. I do this every day :)

Comment: did you try it combined with the c:out tag? check my change in the answer

Answer (score 0):

In Expression Language there should be variable name we put like following are

like this